# Silverlight image viewer control suggestions

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, image, png

Can anyone suggest a good control that can be used to display images (png's most likely and it will always be one type that I can dictate).  The images would be available server side only so I don't have to worry about clients uploading anything.  Just displaying images on  a server.

### The control needs to have the following functionality:

1. Zoom in / out image and ability to pan around zoomed image.
2. Rotate image
3. Page back and forth through images
4. Image area set to whatever size (eg. 200x400) and image fitted to control size with the zoom ability to improve resolution.
5. Define a default zoom level and position within image.
6. Ability to full screen the image control

### Nice to have features:

1. Overlay some type images on top of original image (like lines, boxes, notes etc)
2. Open source

I would prefer to use some type of Silverlight control.

**EDIT:** Did a little more investigation and I found some features of silverlight controls that would REALLY useful such as the expand to full screen.  Have the control being small on the page and a button that allows the use to full screen the image control is a big plus.  I still haven't been able to find one that can do everything I need though.

**EDIT:** Only looking for Silverlight options now.  I have updated the title and description to reflect the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own silverlight control from scratch.  Works real well and the look and feel is amazing with all the animation type features you can use to manipulate everything from button presses to images etc. I was able to do a lot of customization the user wanted.

Silverlight has impressed me.

Comment: Mind sharing how you overcame this?

Answer (score 2):

ShineDraw.com has a comparison between 6 silverlight and flash image rotators. It explains how they work with some code and examples. The sourcecode is available. You should definitly have a look at those:

http://www.shinedraw.com/3d-illusion/6-new-silverlight-image-rotators/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a combination of one of these [jQuery plugins for images](http://www.noupe.com/ajax/37-more-shocking-jquery-plugins.html) may help.

Maybe a combination of the Slider Gallery and the Crop might help. You'd have to merge them into a single control yourself, but it's a step.
If you care for another image viewer in the slideshow model, try this [jQuery slideViewer written by Gian Carlo Mingati](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/imagestrip/imageslide-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what types of images you are looking to display, but there are some answers in this question:

[Previewing TIF documents on the Web (.Net C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939221/previewing-tif-documents-on-the-web-net-c/939809#939809)

Also, Silverlight: [cross platform embeddable large image viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451621/cross-platform-embeddable-large-image-viewer)

Depending on what you're displaying and whether or not you can make assumptions, the [Microsoft Office Document Imaging Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8f93e445-b1cf-4477-a373-e17417d616bc&displaylang=en) is a cheap, browser-embeddable option (i.e., free if your users all have Office 2003 or later).

Comment: Office is something that will most likely not be on all user's computers so Microsoft Office Document Imaging Viewer is not an option.  I have also added some more details to the requirements to make the question a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try vectorlight.net toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Please look up DeepZoom, it has an impressive zooming capabilities. As far as other things go, you can probably implement them yourself :)